# How to separate commands into files Vorpal.js

Tags: vorpal.js

I have many commands and each of them is long.
For example, I have:

- `create`
- `read`
- `update`
- `delete`

I want to put them in separate files:

- `./commands/create.js`
- `./commands/read.js`
- `./commands/update.js`
- `./commands/delete.js`

and I want to require them in `app.js`:

```
require('./commands/create.js');
// ...
```

so I can:

```
node app.js create HelloWorld
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
// create.js

function create(args, cb) {
  // ... your logic
}

module.exports = function (vorpal) {
  vorpal
    .command('create')
    .action(create);
}
```

Then in your main file, you can do:

```
// main.js

const vorpal = Vorpal();

vorpal
  .use(require('./create.js'))
  .use(require('./read.js'))
  .show();
```

[More on this here.](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal/wiki/Docs-%7C-Creating-Extensions)

Comment: I've tried this and when I ask for list of commands by TAB TAB key press. I got the commands twice. Once with full list of commands and second time with only "help quit" commands